# Can we trigger an alert by sending message in Discord Using UIPAth

Tags: uipath

While Using UIPath i have a situation where user needs to be alerted on a specific condition. This message should be sent in Discord. Is it possible to Open/access Discord and send message through UIPath.

Comment: Sure why not? Please look in the UiPath academy how to do this simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

httprequest activity under API solves the issue if proper webhook url is provided. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to create a bot and apply a time trigger to poll for the new messages.

Creating the message automatically is easier to do with a web-hook but creating a bot would be more sustainable